# deleting all documents in Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I delete all the documents held by a `Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation` object?

EDIT1

I need to delete all the documents having the highest invoice for each customer. I can fetch all the documents I wish to delete with the following code

```
collection.find.aggregate([
{ :$group => { _id: "$customer_id", highest: { :$max => "$invoice" }}}
])
```

Now How can I delete all of them?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "delete them"? Do you mean you have an aggregation result that points to documents you want to delete? More detail is required about what you are asking here.

Comment: Can you show us what your result looks like?

Comment: a Mongo::Collection::View::Aggregation

Comment: Your actual result. In json.

Comment: I'm doing it in Ruby and the query returns hundreds of documents. Do you wish to see all of them?

Comment: I just want to see if there is an _id in it.

Comment: This is 1 returned document `{"_id"=>116, "highest"=>260817593.4619382}`

Answer (score 0):

In the shell you can use forEach to iterate results and remove each document.

```
collection.find.aggregate([{ :$group => { _id: "$customer_id", highest: { :$max => "$invoice" }}}])
.forEach(function(row){
   collection.remove({customer_id: row._id});
})
```

Comment: This is an example for mongo shell; but I believe for ruby you can achieve the similar result using a basic for loop. As far as I know there isn't any command for deleting results of an aggregation; so you need to use some kind of a loop structure to iterate result set.

Comment: there is a problem with the solution above. In my collection I have many document with the same customer_id and I wish to delete only the one with highest invoice.  My aggregate sets _id as customer_id and the remove deletes all the document with customer_id from the collection and not only the one I wish.

Comment: Then use the highest value n your remove query combined with the customer id. You already have that value in your aggregation result.

Comment: Unfortunately undefined method `remove' for #<Mongo::Collection>

Comment: İn shell db.yourcollectionname.remove should work. If you try this on ruby I dont know exact syntax.

Comment: Thanks but my issue is with Ruby MongoDB Driver